# Text Alignment in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I made custom cells for my universal app. In iPhone screen text is normal but when I moved to iPad Screen text starts from the very left (shown in picture below). How can I move it right a bit (10px maybe). Is there a way to start the text label from 10px right in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
method? Thanks in advance.

[image: iPad UITableView Screen]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell2";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


    UIImage *background = [self cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width);

    UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
    cellBackgroundView.image = background;
    cell.backgroundView = cellBackgroundView;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How are you setting up your cells now? Post some code of how your custom cells are created

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the text inset in the field, override '-editingRectForBounds:'

```
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
     return CGRectInset( bounds , 10 , 10 );
}
```

If you want to move the label inside the cell, you can create a custom UITableViewCell class and override layoutSubviews

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
     [super layoutSubviews];
     self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 310, 20);
}
```

The cell can be initialised like this

```
cell = [[YOUR_CUSTOM_CELL_CLASS alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

---

**Edit**

In your table view controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Dequeue if possible of course
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[CustomCellClass alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Identifier"];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Should be indented";

    return cell;
}
```

In your CustomCellClass:

`- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 310, 20);
}`

Then the text label will be indented 100 points :)

Source:
Just did it

Comment: I created a custom cell class and override layoutSubviews but it did not work.